# How do I parse a basic XML file with NSXMLParser?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, cocoa-touch, nsxmlparser

I am trying to figure out NSXMLParser for my iPhone app and while I generally understand how it works, I am still a little confused about how to extract the values I need.

The XML result that I am parsing is very basic. it is like so:

```
<start>
 <status>300</status>
 <record>
  <title>The Title</title>
  <content>Some content</content>
 </record>
</start>
```

I need to do 3 things:
Get the value of status. 
Get the value of content from the first record. There may come a response that offers multiple "record" elements so I need to only get the first.

I can't figure out how to simply do that. Most all of the examples I have seen involve creating a separate object to populate this data into and I can't see that being necessary for 2 values. Can anyone tell me how to pull these 2 pieces of data out and only for the first record?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing that happens when the `NSXMLParser` encounters an XML tag is that the delegate method `parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:` is called; you'll probably only need to use the `elementName` variable here. Then, the XML parser reads the characters in the tag and calls `parser:foundCharacters:` with the contents. Finally `parser:didEndElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName` is called.

The approach that I've taken, as Apple uses in the *SeismicXML* examlple, is to use the methods as follows:

1. In `parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:`, compare the string of the element name to a known value to see if it's a string you care about. If so, then set an instance variable (an `NSMutableString`; I'll call it `contentOfCurrentXMLProperty`) to an empty string. Otherwise set it to `nil`.
2. In `parser:foundCharacters:`, append the found characters to `contentOfCurrentXMLProperty`.
3. In `parser:didEndElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName`, assign the value of `contentofCurrentXMLProperty` to whatever the appropriate variable is.

See the *SeismicXML* example for more information.

A couple of things about your specific case: first, since the XML parser only returns strings, you'll need to convert the string to an integer (or whatever data type you're using) for `status`.

Second, since you only want the first value for `record`, in `parser:didStartElement:...` I'd set up a `BOOL` that flags whether you've already seen a  `record` tag before and, if so, set `contentOfCurrentXMLProperty` to `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

Keeping in mind that NSXMLParser is SAX-like event-based parser, you must set up your parser, start it and listen for key events.

Set the parser up:

`NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];

    [parser setDelegate:self];

    [parser parse];`

Override these methods:

`– parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:

– parser:didEndElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:

– parser:foundCharacters:`

Your function must basically say:

- When you reach the next start of a tag:

`-(void)parser: didStartElement:(NSString *) namespaceURI:(NSString *) qualifiedName:(NSString *) attributes:(NSDictionary *)`

- If that tag's name is "status":

`[elementName isEqualToString:@"status"]`

- Give me the tag's string data:

`- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *) foundCharacters:(NSString *)`

`...`

`[<your statusValueHolder as NSMutableString> appendString:<foundCharacters' parameter>]`

`...`

You can apply the same logic for the other case (search for the first start of a tag named "record", abort on reaching the end of tag, named "record", etc)

Have a look at this and try it at home: [Make NSXMLParser your friend..](http://codesofa.com/blog/archive/2008/07/23/make-nsxmlparser-your-friend.html) Also see API Reference Docs for NSXMLParser for additional delegate methods for NSXMLParser's delegate.